# "aptitude safe-upgrade" calculating something. Worth waiting?

Tags: linux, debian, aptitude

```
# aptitude safe-upgrade
<calculating something>
<a day passed, I connected additional swap space>
...
open: 310823; closed: 418353; defer: 82; conflict: 173
<and counting... It eats 2340M of virtual memory>
```

1. Is it going to calculate forever (until memory exhausted) or something worthy will come up in the end?
2. How to optimise "safe-upgrade"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think I've ever seen aptitude ponder an upgrade for more than a minute, if that, so I'd definitely kill it and start over.

If you haven't already done so, `aptitude install aptitude dpkg` is usually a good place to start, so that you can be sure the bulk of the upgrade will be handled by the best available tools.  This step alone may fix whatever is causing your aptitude to go off into space.

If that doesn't do it, I'd take a look at the list of packages available for upgrade and start manually doing a couple at a time until I either discover the cause of the problem or things get into a state where `aptitude safe-upgrade` is able to handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Known bug in aptitude: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=373846

Upgrades with apt is recommended since Debian Lenny, released in 2009: https://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#minimal-upgrade

If you want the exact same behaviour as **aptitude safe-upgrade**, it seems to be: **apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs --autoremove**